# Fetching address and values of opened file

Tags: python, algorithm, bigdata, memory-address

I need to read a particular byte from a big binary file using Python. Using f.seek() takes a long time. Is there any method to fetch the address of the first byte of file and then add the address to reach to a particular byte in Python?

For example, given a text file containing
`asddfrgd`

get address of a, add 5, and then fetch the resulting value (which is 'r', assuming 1 byte for each letter).

Comment: What platform are you on (Windows, Linux...)?

Comment: I am currently using windows but i can switch to linux if there is a sol in linux

Comment: You can try using [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) to map it into memory. As far as I know, it should be faster than loading the entire file using `f.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear. I assume that you want to fetch all values that are 5 bytes after an `"a"` in your example, such that `"aardvark"` gets `"a"` and `"r"` and the last `"a"` is skipped, because adding 5 goes beyond the end of the string.

Here's a solution that returns a list of such values by scanning the file linearly without jumping, byte by byte:

```
def find_past(fn, which, step):
    """ Read file 'fn' and return all elements 'step' bytes after 
        each occurrence of 'which'.
    """

    f = open(fn, "rb")

    n = 0               # current byte address
    res = []            # list of result bytes
    next = []           # list of next byte addresses to consider

    while True:
        c = f.read(1)

        if c == "":
            break

        if next and next[0] == n:
            res.append(c)
            next.pop(0)

        if c == which:
            next.append(n + step)

        n += 1

    f.close()
    return res
```

Keeping track of the lists and byte offsets should be cheaper than `f.seek()`, but I haven't tried that on large data.